# iOS App crashing when only a single JSON result is returned

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app searches a database and returns the results via JSON and displays it in a UITableView. Most of the time everything works fine but my app crashes when a search returns a single result. It can handle 0, or 2-100 but when it gets 1, boom, crash.

Here is the error that it spits out:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to 
instance 0x8d84680
```

And brings up this line of code:

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [[UserInfo sharedUserInfo].userSearchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Here is the code for the rest of the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [[userInfo sharedUserInfo].userSearchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"system_title"];
    }
    else {

    UILabel *TitleLable = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    TitleLable.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];


    UILabel *systemTitleLable = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    systemTitleLable.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"system_title"];

    }
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you try searching for "objectAtIndex unrecognized selector"?  This question has been asked hundreds of times…

Comment: post your json for 1 item and 2 item. i can answer u

Comment: @AaronBrager I did, but I don't know why it works with multiple results and not one.

Comment: @DookieMan Your API is returning an array of dictionaries if there are >1 objects, or a dictionary alone if there is only 1.  Your code only handles arrays.  It needs to check if it's a dictionary instead of an array, and handle that case.

Comment: @AaronBrager That's right, forgive the noobie. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're userSearchArray is an instance of NSDictionary. This happens if you have only one "object" in a JSON String. If there are more than one the JSON deserializer puts the "objects" in an array like you expect. All you have to do is to check the result of:

```
[[userInfo sharedUserInfo].userSearchArray
```

like this:

```
if([[[userInfo sharedUserInfo].userSearchArray isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    //work directly with the dictionary
} else {
    //work with the array.
}
```

Comment: This solution will work, but technically it's the API's response that chooses the format, not the serializer. (The API could pass back an array of 1 dictionary if it wanted.)

Comment: @AaronBrager I used this solution to do exactly what you just suggested. I had the app create an array of the single returned dictionary and kept the UITableView intact. Works great now.